# How to get values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string with values i want to use. I'm parsing this string as an JSON object using $.parseJSON. However I'm having problems getting the actual values.

In this case I'm trying to get the value of the key "textarea1" which is "banana". What is the correct syntax for getting the values. I tried obj.texts.textarea1, but it didn't work.

The string looks like this:

```
var obj = "[{\"texts\":[{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\Apple\",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}]}]";
```

Script:

```
var oldVal = $.parseJSON(obj);
```

Comment: "Im parsing this string as an JSON object using $.parseJSON" — Why don't you show us how? You have several bits of code, but you seem to be showing them in the wrong order with bits missing. Try putting together a real test case.

Comment: `var d = JSON.parse(obj)[0].texts[0].textarea1`

Comment: and check the value of appel i think you have missed a double quote over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. missing quote on \Apple
2. You access obj but need to access oldVal
3. you have nested arrays so you need array notation to get at them or flatten the arrays
4. You do not need jQuery and likely have not defined it. JSON.parse will work

```js
var obj = "[{\"texts\":[{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\"Apple\",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}]}]";

var oldVal = JSON.parse(obj);

console.log(oldVal[0].texts[0].textarea1)
```

If you want to access `oldVal.texts.textarea1` you need to remove the array:

```
var obj = "{\"texts\":{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\"Apple\",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}}";
```

Comment: Hmm i see where i was wrong now. Thanks for explaining. Make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**1st Option**
You need not to change anything. Just fix your JSON in correct format.

You can use [JsonLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to check your `JSON` is correct or not. Then Proceed further.

```
var obj = "[{\"texts\":[{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\"Apple\",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}]}]";

var oldVal = JSON.parse(obj);

alert(oldVal[0].texts[0].textarea1)
```

---

**2nd Option**

If you want to get the result like `obj.texts.textarea1` then you'll have to change your data as following.

Format Your JSON 
Remove all `[` and `]` from your json.
then do.

```
var a = '{"texts": {"default": true,"bread-texts": false,"textarea1": "Banana","textarea2": "Kiwi","textarea3": "Apple","textarea4": "coffe","textarea5": "Tea","signature": true,"profile": "header","fontsize": "26","fontsize-headers": "10.5","fontcolor": "#0000","textfont": "header-large","textsub1": "Bold","font": "ICA%20Text","textsub": "Regular","textsize": "20","textsize-signature": "9.5","textsizesmall": "5.5","textsizesmall-placer": "2.75","vers-placer": "false","text-colored": "%23000000","s-all-customers": true,"new-customers": true,"undefined": ""} }';

var obj = JSON.parse(a);
```

Then

`obj.texts.textarea1`;

You've created array in your `JSON` so for that you need to do array accessing.

[image]

Comment: You just ignored his data format and removed his arrays

Comment: @mplungjan He is using` " ` inside `"` and instead of that I'm using `'` and `"`. So I provided him solution for how he can access object to object. He want the solution like Object to object. He want to ignore `array` notation

Comment: He has nested arrays you have just removed: `[{\"texts\":[{` He did not know he needed array notation

Comment: @mplungjan he have mentioned that he want to access like `obj.texts.textarea1` so i did the formatting.

Comment: No, he said he TRIED obj.texts.textarea1 and it didn't work. So you need to tell him that IF he wants to use that notation he needs to remove the [] but if not, then use array notation.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for  redirecting me to correct path. :)

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is of type string. You can not index it as object in the form `obj.texts`. You are parsing it using `$.parseJSON`, then use the **object** returned by that call:

```
var oldVal = $.parseJSON( obj );
var value = oldVal[0].texts[0].textarea1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.

At this place, you are missing a quote:

```
\"textarea3\":\Apple\" (escaped)
"textarea3":Apple" (unescaped)
```

JSON parsing will fail at this point.

After fixing this typo, I can easily access your JSON items this way:

```js
var obj = "[{\"texts\":[{\"default\":true,\"bread-texts\":false,\"textarea1\":\"Banana\",\"textarea2\":\"Kiwi\",\"textarea3\":\"Apple\",\"textarea4\":\"coffe\",\"textarea5\":\"Tea\",\"signature\":true,\"profile\":\"header\",\"fontsize\":\"26\",\"fontsize-headers\":\"10.5\",\"fontcolor\":\"#0000\",\"textfont\":\"header-large\",\"textsub1\":\"Bold\",\"font\":\"ICA%20Text\",\"textsub\":\"Regular\",\"textsize\":\"20\",\"textsize-signature\":\"9.5\",\"textsizesmall\":\"5.5\",\"textsizesmall-placer\":\"2.75\",\"vers-placer\":\"false\",\"text-colored\":\"%23000000\",\"s-all-customers\":true,\"new-customers\":true,\"undefined\":\"\"}]}]";

// using JSON.parse
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.parse(obj)[0].texts[0].textarea1;
// or using jQuery
document.body.innerHTML += $.parseJSON(obj)[0].texts[0].textarea1;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```